# Eclipse Kepler wont allow me to install a plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I keep trying to install a plugin with Eclipse Kepler, but keep getting this error:
[image]

What is this and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the e(fx)clipse release you are trying to install requires Eclipse 4.4 Luna.

Comment: Have you tried asking on the e(fx)clipse forum (https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/259/)? The project's development team seems to be active in answering questions.

Comment: @E-Riz They seem to be suggesting things that don't work :(.

Comment: @greg-449 is right, the latest version of e(fx)clipse requires Eclipse Luna. See the installation page at https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html

Comment: @greg-449 You should make an answer to get credit, I'm pretty sure you're correct about the cause.